# How to create the child page to parent page in wiki

Tags: ibm-sbt

I am posting a new query regarding wiki page creation programmatically using SBT.

I tried to create the wiki page under one parent page but did not find a link to map both parent and child. Every time I create the wiki page it gets created independently without community(non-community wiki page).

I working with a playground but it is throwing some exceptions.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code specifically to set a child page. You'll have to extend the wiki service in the sbt to make it work for child pages.

Per http://bastide.org/2014/05/06/creating-a-new-wiki-page-as-a-child/

API Details
URL: https://{hostname}:{port}/wikis/basic/api/wiki/{wiki-label}/feed
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

You may have to add the X-Update-Nonce header.

You have to update the XML with the parentUuid – eg bd586bb6-d9b2-4527-b9a0-0f9b0d3c1e3f

When you complete the post, you’ll have a new page with a parent page.

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<category term="Test" label="Test"></category>
<category term="page" label="page" scheme="tag:ibm.com,2006:td/type"></category>
<parentUuid xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">parentUuid</parentUuid>
<title>Tes4</title>
<summary></summary>
<label xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">Tes4</label>
<content type="text/html"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;"><!ENTITY lt "&#60;#60;"><!ENTITY gt "&#62;#62;"><!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"><!ENTITY apos "&#39;"><!ENTITY quot "&#34;">]><div></div></content></entry>
```

Comment: Thanks paul your answer worked for me but unable to add the description/summary to the wiki page.may be something is missing.
Iam using the same method of adding the child page.Can you please tell me where should i check that part.when Checked in the connections site response there it shows the summary but the content tag is empty.

Comment: After lot of investigations i came up with one solution is while passing above content xml replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;.This is adding content to the page but still <!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;......................   >  with entities are not working ,
So I passed DOCTYPE html [] and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Hi Srinivas In SBT if you are using wikiservice.js, you just need to make sure you are using correct wiki label.

Here is the sample code for adding a page to wiki named ***manishkataria***

```
var wikiPage = wikiService.newWikiPage(); 
wikiPage.setWikiLabel("manishkataria"); 
wikiPage.setTitle("dummytitle"); 
wikiPage.setSummary("dummysummary"); 
wikiPage.setTags("tag2"); 
wikiPage.setLabel("uniquelabel1"); 
wikiPage.setContent("dummy content");
```

Comment: i can now add the page to the wiki and using paul's input i can able to add the child page also but unable to add the summary to the pages both to the parent and also to the child .